# Operations with only some of the components of 2 vectors

Tags: r, vector, exponential

i was wondering if someone could help me with the following thing:
I have 2 vectors let's say:

```
A<-c(10,20,-10,6,-15,5)
B<-1:length(A)
```

Due to the fact that A may have more or less components, and I want to do A^B but only with the positive values of A, so i would have something like:

C<-(10^1,20^2,6^4,5^6)=> (10,400,1296,15625)

I've tried with a "for" and a variable'i' that goes trought the lenght of the vectors and also with data frames, but normally it does the operation for all the components and not just for the psoitive ones or creates a new vector and do D<-(10^1,20^2,6^3,5^4) and that's not what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about subsetting first:

```
A[sign(A)==1]
#[1] 10 20  6  5
B[sign(A)==1]
#[1] 1 2 4 6

A[sign(A)==1]^B[sign(A)==1]
#[1]    10   400  1296 15625
```

You could also subset afterwards:

```
(A^B)[sign(A)==1]
#[1]    10   400  1296 15625
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it really helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

Try `subset`

```
> subset(A^B, A > 0)
[1]    10   400  1296 15625
```

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it